# A Chess Lock Puzzle?

Tags: chess

I was recently talking to one of my friends who played chess (much better than me, I'll admit). He said he had a different kind of chess problem, one that may be a little easier, or that may be a little bit harder than usual. He said it was a chess lock puzzle.

He then grabbed two(!) chess sets and set up the following position:

[image]

He challenged me to find the least number of moves to capture the black king, using the following rules:

> 1. White gets an infinite number of moves.
> 2. White may only capture undefended pieces, and the black king (checkmate isn't a thing, just capture the black king)
> 3. Rooks are the only keys that work. You must capture the black king with a rook.

He said his best was to do it in 17 moves. Can you do it quicker?

Comment: Just to clarify, do black's pieces capture whites pieces if they are in a position where they could?

Comment: @gabbo1092 no, but white is not permitted to capture black pieces that are guarded.

Comment: @gabbo1092 I think that black pieces can't do any moves. We only consider white moves. Am I right?

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz yes.

Comment: Might Black have moved in the past, even though Black will never move again?  If so, depending upon what Black just did, there could be a four-move solution (1. dxe e.p. or 1. fxe e.p., followed by 2. e7  3.e8=R 4. Rxa8)

Comment: @supercat remember, my friend set up the position, with no prior moves. I knew someone would try that ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think there's a quicker way to do it.

> Rb2 Nb1 Rd2 Bd1 Rf2 B3e2 Rf4 Bgf3 Rg4 Rxg7 Rg8 Rxa8

for 12 moves.

Comment: Yeah, this was it (and this gets the check for the earlier timestamp)

Comment: Darn I was just finishing double checking mine and you just beat me! Congrats!

Comment: Move 6 is ambiguous as written. You should replace the 'f' by a '3'.

Answer (score 8):

I think I found a solution in 12 moves:

> 1.Rb2 
>  2. Nb1  
> 3. Rd2  
>  4.Bd1  
>  5. Rf2  
> 6.Be2  
> 7.Rf4  
> 8.Bf3  
> 9.Rg4  
> 10. Rxg7  
> 11.Rg8  
> 12.Rxa8

Comment: I think you were about 28 seconds behind @Especially Lime unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

I can do it in 15 moves by my count.

> The key is to move it around like one of those sliding block puzzles (like rush hour first. Then you only need to get a pawn promoted to a rook. No need to move any existing rooks out.

Spoiler Break

> Rb2
> Nb1
> Rd2
> Bd1
> Ne2
> Nf4
> Ne6
> Nxg7
> Ne8
> Nxf6
> Ng8
> f6
> f7
> f8=R
> Rxa8

And will look something like this (apologies if I mess something up, I set the picture up after the fact, the annotation should be right.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrcVl.png

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done in 10 moves:

> 1.Rb2
> 2.Nb1
> 3.Rd2
> 4.Bd1
> 5.Be2
> 6.Nf3
> 7.Ng5
> 8.Ne6
> 9.Nc7
> 10.Na8

Comment: Make sure to look at Rule 3, this would be perfectly valid if that wasn't there.